# giving a variable the value of one every 30 seconds

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In android if a button is clicked i want a countdown to start from 30 and countdown to 0. I created a code with a basic countdown method but the problem is it doesn't continue to countdown if the activity or application closes.

What i want to do is for the activity or just the countdown to continue ticking down in the background until it hits 0 in which it'll change variable B to the value of 1.

I have expanded from my original model thinking i could compare dates times from when the button was clicked + 30 seconds to when the activity is called up upon again. But so far i have come to a stump in comparing two datetimes in android.

Any help?

Comment: can you please update your code here?

Comment: please show my code i have update it

Answer (score 1):

What you likely want is an async task to run in the background. Something like:

```
private class JohnnysPollTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> {
        /**
         * The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and delivers
         * it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute()
         */
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... millis) {
            try {
                int waited = 0;         
                                int duration = 30000;
                while (waited < duration) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    waited += 1000;

                    if (waited>=duration) {
                        b=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            }

            return 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a service instead of an activity.

Comment: I don't want to waste unnecessary CPU memory for such a simple task though. is there any other way?

Comment: I think it is comment so plz use comment instead of Answer

Answer (score 0):

Implement [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

inside `service`.